# In Debian WiFi only working when I reboot from windows

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, drivers, firmware

lsusb of the WiFi device is

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
```

I am using Debian and have windows dual booted. when I boot Debian on first startup the WiFi driver fails to load (hens no power in WiFi adapter).

but whats strange is when I boot into windows and give the adapter a taste of electricity and reboot into Debian again WiFi just works fine.

I have checked that Debian loads the firmware MT7601 when I boot it second time restarting from windows.

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this so I don't have to boot windows first every time.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
git clone --depth 1 git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

And replace your firmware file in `/lib/firmware`. If that doesn't help, please try using the latest available stable kernel (`5.9.4` at the moment) - no idea what your distro is and how it can be done but I'm sure you can google it up. If that still doesn't help, report a bug at https://bugzilla.kernel.org/

Lastly make sure there are no errors logged in `dmesg` in regard to your wireless adapter. It would be great if you posted two of `dmesg` outputs - when the adapter works and when it doesn't work.